# Testing if warnings are sent as logmessages

Tags: python, logging, pytest, python-logging

I have set `logging.captureWarnings(True)` in an application, and would like to test if warnings are logged correctly. I'm having difficulties understanding some of the behavior I'm seeing where tests are influencing each other in ways that I don't quite get.

Here is an example test suite which reproduces the behavior I'm seeing:

**test_warning_logs.py**

```py
import warnings
import logging


def test_a(caplog):
    logging.captureWarnings(True)
    logging.basicConfig()
    
    warnings.warn("foo")

    assert "foo" in caplog.text

def test_b(caplog):
    logging.captureWarnings(True)
    logging.basicConfig()
    
    warnings.warn("foo")

    assert "foo" in caplog.text
```

Both tests are identical. When run in isolation (`pytest test_warning_logs.py -k test_a`, `pytest test_warning_logs.py -k test_b`), they each pass. When both of them are executed in the same run (`pytest test_warning_logs.py`), only the first one will pass:

```
============== test session starts ========================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.2, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/me
plugins: mock-3.10.0, dependency-0.5.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

test_warning_logs.py .F                                                                                                                                                              [100%]

==================== FAILURES =============================
_____________________ test_b ______________________________

caplog = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at 0x7f8041857c40>

    def test_b(caplog):
        logging.captureWarnings(True)
        logging.basicConfig()
    
        warnings.warn("foo")
    
>       assert "foo" in caplog.text
E       AssertionError: assert 'foo' in ''
E        +  where '' = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at 0x7f8041857c40>.text
[...]
```

### Additional Information

First I thought that the commands `logging.captureWarnings` and `logging.basicConfig` aren't idempotent, and running them more than once is the issue. But if you remove them from `test_b`, it still fails.

My current assumption is that it's a pytest issue, because when the code is executed without it, both warnings are logged:

```py
# add this block to the bottom of test_warning_logs.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock

    test_a(MagicMock(text="foo"))
    test_b(MagicMock(text="foo"))
```

`$ python test_warning_logs.py`

```
WARNING:py.warnings:/home/me/test_warning_logs.py:9: UserWarning: foo
  warnings.warn("foo")

WARNING:py.warnings:/home/me/test_warning_logs.py:17: UserWarning: foo
  warnings.warn("foo")
```

Comment: Hint: what happens if you try using `warnings.warn('foo')` at the REPL, twice in a row?

Comment: The second one gets swallowed, because `warnings` treats interactive commands as files, so they are effectively on the same line, `<input>:1:`. That's not the case for my code though, or else the example at the bottom wouldn't work. Also, the second test can be changed to `warnings.warn("bar")`, and the same error still shows up when running it with pytest.

Comment: Yeah, what I thought was a lead was not - I saw this from the existing answer, too.

Comment: It might just be a straight up bug, if I don't get a working answer soon-ish I'll just repost this to pytest's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option to log the warnings using the `logging` module instead of `warnings`, then you won't face this issue.

```
import logging


def test_a(caplog):
    logging.captureWarnings(True)
    logging.basicConfig()

    logging.warning("foo")

    assert "foo" in caplog.text


def test_b(caplog):
    logging.captureWarnings(True)
    logging.basicConfig()

    # This will be deprecated eventually, you can use logging.warning() instead
    logging.warn("foo")

    assert "foo" in caplog.text
```

I don't know why it doesn't work using warnings module. According to their documentation:

> Repetitions of a particular warning for the same source location are
> typically suppressed.

So I assumed this is what is happening here, but even calling `warnings.resetwarnings()` does not change the behavior.

Comment: It's not me raising the warnings, it's one of the libraries I'm using. And yeah, it's not the repetition-suppression's fault, because the warnings are on different lines.